# Flutter Sqlite Exception,No such table, SQL logic Error

Tags: flutter, flutter-moor

I'm creating on my own a to-do app using Flutter. When I compile and try to insert a data in sqlite database, I got this error `Flutter Sqlite Exception,No such table task, SQL logic Error`.

Note: I use `moor_ffi`, `moor`
,and generate the `database.g.dart` file using  command `flutter packages pub run build_runner build`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From moor [documentation](https://moor.simonbinder.eu/faq/):

> **Why am I getting no such table errors?**
>
> If you add another table after your app has already been installed,
>   you need to write a migration that covers creating that table. If
>   you’re in the process of developing your app and want to use un- and
>   reinstall your app instead of writing [migrations](https://moor.simonbinder.eu/docs/advanced-features/migrations/), that’s fine too.
>   Please note that your apps data might be backed up on Android, so
>   manually deleting your app’s data instead of a reinstall is necessary
>   on some devices.

So everytime you have modified your database, you need to re-install your app or  increase the schema version in your database.

```
  @override
  int get schemaVersion => 2;
```

Comment: Thanks, you saved me from so much more pain